# display an Image

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

i am a total c++ and opencv beginner, and i want to learn it. i am working with visual 2008.as a lesson i tried to display a .jpg picture but the program wont compile. when debugging, i get this error:

> 1>main.cpp 1>c:\users\ralf\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\3)\3)\main.cpp(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file: 'cv.h': No such file or directory
>
> 1>Build log was saved
>   at "file://c:\Users\ralf\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\3)\3)\Debug\BuildLog.htm" 1>3) - 1 error(s), 0
>   warning(s)
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

i suppose it is something about the linker and which files i have to include, and how....^^
i wrote the following under project->properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies (Active(Debug) on the left corner of the window):

```
opencv_highgui230d.lib 
opencv_core230d.lib 
opencv_cv.lib
```

in Release i wrote:

```
opencv_highgui230.lib
opencv_core230.lib
```

last but not least, here is my code

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h> 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "IMG_7321_.jpg" );
    cvNamedWindow( "MyJPG", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("MyJPG", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "MyJPG" );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux:

```
g++ -o _test test.cpp -lcv -lhighgui
```

Windows:

```
@"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -O3 -Wall -Iinclude \
-o test.exe test.cpp \
libopencv_core230.dll libopencv_highgui230.dll libopencv_imgproc230.dll
```

source code, test.cpp:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2) return -1;
  char *filename_i = argv[1];
  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(filename_i, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  cvShowImage("Test Window", img);
  cvWaitKey(5*1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Needed DLLs:

```
$ ls -1 *.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libopencv_calib3d230.dll
libopencv_contrib230.dll
libopencv_core230.dll
libopencv_features2d230.dll
libopencv_flann230.dll
libopencv_gpu230.dll
libopencv_highgui230.dll
libopencv_imgproc230.dll
libopencv_legacy230.dll
libopencv_ml230.dll
libopencv_objdetect230.dll
libopencv_video230.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
```

You can get my package from URL: http://pacify.ru/download/opencv-showimage-test.tgz

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i dont quite get what i should do^^

Comment: where do i have to place those .dlls?

Comment: i downloaded your package but visual still wont compile with the same error as before

Comment: My package containing the DLL, used for Code::Blocks, but not for Visual Studio. But you can try this DLL to link with your Visual Studio-project dynamically.

Comment: So, your message: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cv.h': No such file or directory" suggests that it is not the path to CV-include directory in the Visual Studio Project Preferences.